# When did the insult “up yours” come into existence?

Tags: slang, phrase-origin

The movie *Blazing Saddles* used everything and anything to get a laugh.  When the African American sheriff, newly assigned to a rural town, patrolled the main thoroughfare he happened upon an elderly lady and greeted her kindly.  She gave him a deadpan look then said, “Up yours, nigger!”.  The racial slur, having long lost most of its punch at the point in the movie wasn’t nearly as funny as the “up yours” portion.  Without speculating on the what of “yours” the speaker is referring too, when did saying “up yours” start being used?

Comment: If the N-word lost its punch, folks wouldn't be saying "the N-word."

Comment: It lost its punch *in the movie*.  Desensitization.

Comment: It came into existence right after the insult "Shove it up your ass!" came into existence.

Answer (score 2):

Green’s Dictionary of Slang cites usage examples from early ‘30s:

> [up yours!](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/qsv7qfi#wjn3oha://) [euphemistic abbreviation of up your arse! excl.]
>
> 1. (orig. US) an excl. of contempt.
>
> 1933  [US]    J.T. Farrell Gas-House McGinty 157: Yeah and up yours too.

Comment: And “up your arse”?  How do you look this up?

Comment: @DatDiesel - https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/7z5vshi

Comment: Interesting. The OED's first citation isn't till 1956, from crime novelist Ed McBain. They agree on "up your arse!" though.